# Young and Freedman magnetic force error

Tags: electromagnetism

I think I've found an error in the 14th edition of Y&F. Figure 27.37 (p 928) is:
[image: Figure 27.37]
Am I right in thinking the net forces should be switched so that they point in the opposite directions?

Comment: I'm more concerned about the $d\vec{\mathbf{F}}$ forces that appear to be parallel to the central magnetic field line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the μ indicates the dipole moment of the loop, then the current flow is up on the near  side of the loop and down on the far side.  In that case, the force vectors indicated by dF at the top and bottom of the loop are correct and they do have horizontal components conributing to the shown net force.

Comment: Ah I was seeing the coil incorrectly - I thought the right hand bit of the coil was furthest away. Bit of an optical illusion. Seems obvious now though, thanks